# In Laravel 6 Storage::putFile is storing the given file on just saving the code without me executing the code

Tags: php, laravel

`Storage::putFile('uploads', new File('C:\sandbox\sample.txt'));` is storing the file `sample.txt` with hashed name into the uploads directory everytime I save this code in VSCode without me executing this php code in browser using WAMP or terminal. I am not running any unit tests and also did not even open this page in browser. How is this happening?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Http\File; 

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        Storage::putFile('uploads', new File('C:\sandbox\sample.txt'));
    }
}
```

I expect this code to run when the controller method containing this code is executed but this is storing the file on just saving this code.

Comment: Where is that line of code located?

Comment: It is located in my one of controllers methods.